# How to modify arrays in Processing and send them from serial to Arduino?

Tags: java, arduino, serial-port, processing

I have a code that currently takes values from a controller input in Processing, sends those values over serial to an Arduino Uno that sends those values over radio to another Arduino Uno. I am attempting to change format to send an array for better communication and this is my current failed attempt at that

Current processing code

```
 int status[] = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0}
 void draw
 if (thumblefty > .2)
 {
 status[0]=3;
 }
 if (thumblefty < -.2)
 {
 status[0]=0;
 }
 if (thumbleftx>.2)
 {
 status[0]=1;
 }
 if (thumbleftx<-.2)
 {
 status[1]=2;
 }
 //etc etc on the if statements
 myPort.write(status);
 }
```

This however produces an error line on the myPort.write that says The function “write()” expects parameters like: “write(byte[])”. I do not wish to send a byte, as I want to do more than 1's and 0's in this array. Even when I do modify the code to make it

```
byte status[]={0,0,0,0,0}
```

I do not get the expected results on my receiving arduino

Transmitter code (Arduino)

```
byte state[4];
void loop
state[4] = Serial.read();
radio.write(&state, sizeof(state));
```

Receiving code (Arduino)

```
byte state[4];
void loop
radio.read(&state, sizeof(state));
Serial.println(state[4]);
```

When the controller is in it's up position, I expect an output on the receiving serial of [3,0,0,0,0], but instead the serial port is full of random integers that have no change based on controller position and are not in a byte or array form

I would like help configuring my processing code to send an array, and help figuring out how I can interpret that array over serial and sending over RF24. The end goal is to have the receiving Arduino be able to look at the values in each position of the array, say

```
if state[3]==2
{
motor 2 full power
}
```

And be able to do that for all positions of the array, to have all possible inputs encoded in the array to be deciphered, but I first need my serial port to even receive the array itself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following source code will send a string of random state values from an integer array in Processing to Arduino as comma separated values; the end of the string is terminated by a line feed.
*Addendum:* Original answer edited to convert array integer to a string prior to writing to Arduino, ie str(myState[i]).

**Processing code:**

```
import processing.serial.*;

int[] myState = new int[4];
Serial myPort;

void setup() {
  // Output is in console
  surface.setVisible(false);
  printArray(Serial.list());
 // Set port number for your system
  myPort = new Serial(this, Serial.list()[3], 9600);
}

void draw() {
  if (frameCount % 60 == 0) {
    myState[0] = int(random(4));
    myState[1] = int(random(4));
    myState[2] = int(random(4));
    myState[3] = int(random(4));
    for (int i = 0; i < myState.length-1; i++) {
      myPort.write(str(myState[i]));
      myPort.write(',');
    }
    myPort.write(str(myState[3]) + '\n');
    printArray(myState);
    println("=============");
  }
   
}
```

**Alternate Solution:**
Following source code uses an alternate method of sending array string.  It works well with Arduino code which follows.  An LED was added to the project to demonstrate that array really is being used on the Arduino side since we can't use Serial Monitor (port is tied up by Processing).  You can delete the LED code if you don't want to use it.

```
import processing.serial.*;

int[] myState = new int[4];
Serial myPort;
String inStr;
String outStr;
int x1, x2, x3, x4;
void setup() {
  // Output is in console
  surface.setVisible(false);
  printArray(Serial.list());
  // Set port number for your system
  myPort = new Serial(this, Serial.list()[3], 9600);
}

void draw() {
  if (frameCount % 60 == 0) {
    myState[0] = int(random(4));
    myState[1] = int(random(4));
    myState[2] = int(random(4));
    myState[3] = int(random(4));
    outStr = str(myState[0]) + "," + str(myState[1]) + "," + str(myState[2]) + "," + str(myState[3]) + "\n";
    myPort.write(outStr);
    printArray(myState);
    println("=============");
  }   
}

void serialEvent(Serial p) {
  inStr = p.readStringUntil('\n');
  if (inStr != null) {
    String trimStr = trim(inStr);
    println("receivedBack : " + trimStr);   
}
}
```

**Arduino Code:**

```
const int LED = 12;

int myState[4];

String inStr;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(LED, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
  if (Serial.available() > 0) {
    inStr = Serial.readStringUntil('\n');
    myState[0] = Serial.parseInt(); 
    Serial.println("state[0]"); 
    myState[1] = Serial.parseInt();
    Serial.println("state[1]"); 
    myState[2] = Serial.parseInt(); 
    Serial.println("state[2]");
    myState[3] = Serial.parseInt();
    Serial.println("state[3]");
  }
  
  if(myState[3] == 2){
    digitalWrite(LED, HIGH); 
    delay(2000);
  } else {
    digitalWrite(LED, LOW);
    delay(2000);
  }
  }
```

Comment: I may have not understood your question correctly.  It appears that you may want the reverse of this demo, ie sending an array from Processing to an arduino.  Is this correct?

Comment: That is correct yes! Thank you for the current code but I am indeed trying to send an array from Processing to an Arduino, I apologize for the bad formatting on my question

Comment: See edited answer.

Comment: Your code looks incredible and is working well on the processing side of things, processings console is displaying                                                                  =============
[0] 1
[1] 0
[2] 0
[3] 0
=============                                                                                                          and that first value changes as I move the trigger. I do still have an issue on my receiving side but I think its just how I'm sending it, will work on it, thank you!

Comment: See edited answer for alternate Processing solution with accompanying Arduino code. Original answer edited to convert array integer to string before writing to Arduino.